# Video and audio is button is disabled in custom web part?

Tags: sharepoint-server, ribbon, blog, video-richmedia

I have Integrated the SharePoint ribbon functionality into custom web part using JSOM. In the edit ribbon video and audio, the button is disabled. I added that web part in the blog site. Server publishing feature also activated at site collection level but no luck. Please advise me to solve this issue

Code I Tried

`(function ($) {

   $.fn.SPEditable = function () {

     return this.each(function () {

       $(this).addClass("ms-rte-layoutszone-inner-editable ms-rtestate-write").attr("role", "textbox").attr("aria-haspopup", "true").attr("contentEditable", "true").attr("aria-autocomplete", "both").attr("aria-autocomplete", "both").attr("aria-multiline", "true");

     });

   };

   $.fn.SPNonEditable = function () {

     return this.each(function () {

       $(this).removeClass("ms-rte-layoutszone-inner-editable ms-rtestate-write").removeAttr("role aria-haspopup contentEditable aria-autocomplete aria-multiline");

     });

   };

 })(jQuery);`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, Check things below:

1. Check if you have activated the “Video and Rich Media” site collection feature. If not, activate the site collection feature.

Go to site settings->site collection administration->activate “Video and Rich Media” site collection features.
[image]

2. Add the site into the compatibility mode in IE.

More reference:

Add video, audio, or images to a classic page.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-video-audio-or-images-to-a-classic-page-b5220c61-e56a-40fd-8754-d06a2e38b492

Comment: Ya that feature is already activated in site collection level, still, video and audio button is disabled @Amy_SPWX